# How to change window.location urls with text <input> boxes

Tags: javascript, html, html-input

Ok so I'm making a video game and I want players to be able to select custom files within the game via a text input box. I was able to get everything to work but when I click the Load Level button it will take me to:

.../Custom Levels/undefined.html
I tried messing around with a few other ways but the only other thing I got was:

.../Custom Levels/[object HTMLInputElement].html

```
<div>
    <p><input type="text" id="LVLNK" value="Level Name"></p>
    <p><input type="button" id="MButton" value="Load Level" onclick="LDLVLNK()"></p>
    </div>

<script>
var time = setInterval(10,gameLoop)
var LevelLink; /*put: "var LevelLink = document.getElementById("LVLNK");" to get other link example instead*/

function gameLoop()
{
LevelLink = document.getElementById("LVLNK").value;
}

function LDLVLNK()
{
window.location = "../Custom Levels/" + LevelLink + ".html";
}
```

The file I'm currently trying to access is named "CLevel1"

So I would place CLevel1 in the input box. The gameLoop would set the name toe the LevelLink variable that is then added to the full link in the window.location function located inside of the LDLVLNK function that is activated by the button.

Comment: Your returning a object trying calling it `Levellink.value`.

Comment: He has `.value` in the assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could try the following :

```
function LDLVLNK(){
  location.href = "../Custom Levels/" + LevelLink + ".html";
//here window is optional, location is a globally accessible object
}
```

BTW :
You got it wrong with `setInterval`, you should use `setInterval(gameLoop, 10);`(even though 10 is probably not very good/maintainable by the browser, try 100 and reduce the amount by a touch if it's too much)

Comment: `window.location` and `location.href` do the same thing.

Comment: OP is reporting that he gets [object HTMLInputElement] in his URL. This means that there is also a problem with stringifing a value. This will not solve the problem entirely.

Comment: I see I'll fix that!

Comment: I just fixed it and it worked! Thanks for spotting that!

Comment: @Zomry it was in the post prior to a change to insert `.value` on the selector.

Comment: no it was the gameLoop that was the problem. I think I know why. Beign that the text field loads empty (undefined). The gameloop isn't able to update the LevelLink variable meaning that when the wondow.location is run it runs the undefined value

Comment: That is true, you can add a condition to check if the content matches the pattern `/^\s*$/` (empty string or many white-spaces) and do nothing if it matches

Answer (score 1):

You have the arguments to `setInterval()` backwards, it should be:

```
setInterval(gameLoop, 10);
```

But there's no reason for the `LevelLink` global variable. You can simply get the input value in `LDLVLNK()`:

```
function LDLVLNK() {
    var LevelLink = document.getElementById("LVLNK").value;
    if (LevelLink) {
        window.location = "../Custom Levels/" + LevelLink + ".html";
    } else {
        alert("Nowhere to go to");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey man! Thanks! I looked at your profile before you answered (I was hoping you would, sense your a professional). Thanks for the coding simplification I just added it and it works great! I like the alert addition!

Comment: Would it be possible to testfor if the LevelLink value is the name of a file? For example: If I'm trying to access a file labeled FirstLevel but accidentally put FstLevel. Is it possible to testfor if the name FstLevel is the name if a file and then return an alert if it isn't?

Comment: You could perform an AJAX `GET` request to the URL. If it succeeds, do the redirect, if it fails display an alert.

Comment: Why don't you use a dropdown that lists the valid names, instead of a text box?

Comment: We'll the fact that the custom level's names can change (because there custom) I figured that the only way would be to use a text box. I don;t think you can retrieve file name information with just javascript right?

Comment: No, Javascript doesn't have any direct access to files on the server, it needs to use AJAX. You can write an AJAX script that returns the list of custom levels from the server, and use that to populate the select.